# Why is the function giving an error? discord.py

Tags: python, function, discord, discord.py

```py
def test():
    await message.author.send('ehy')

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
        if message.author.id == 2980828228298:
            test()
```

I can't understand why this simple function isn't working. The error is "await". Any help?

Comment: please share the full error.

Comment: I can't even start the program, there's a syntax error: 'await' outside async function

Comment: The await keyword is only allowed in functions marked with async.

Comment: Could you provide me an example? This is my first time using a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm no `discord.py` master, I don't know anything about it actually. Though I do understand that in order to use `await` it must be inside a `async` function. Using your provided code, I guess you can just return a string in your `test()` function.

```
def test():
    return 'ehy'

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
        if message.author.id == 2980828228298:
            await message.author.send(test())
```